# AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'startswith' in pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

This is the command I use:

```
test=rdd.filter(lambda line:line.startsWith("I"))
test.take(2)
```

Of course, rdd was already made and it worked fine. But test did not work and showing the below the error.

This question can look sily but I am unfamiliar with Pyspark. I got this error in pyspark through the virtual machine. Does anyone know what this error is and please give a solution to fix it. Thanks for any help in advance.

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.runJob.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 24.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 24.0 (TID 13, localhost): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/worker.py", line 101, in main
    process()
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/worker.py", line 96, in process
    serializer.dump_stream(func(split_index, iterator), outfile)
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/serializers.py", line 236, in dump_stream
    vs = list(itertools.islice(iterator, batch))
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 1221, in takeUpToNumLeft
    yield next(iterator)
  File "<ipython-input-44-6f0330afa2d7>", line 1, in <lambda>
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'startswith'

    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$$anon$1.read(PythonRDD.scala:135)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$$anon$1.<init>(PythonRDD.scala:176)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:94)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:277)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:244)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:61)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:203)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1203)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1192)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1191)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1191)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:693)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:693)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:693)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1393)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1354)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
```

My sample input

```
[u'BibNumber,ItemBarcode,ItemType,Collection,CallNumber,CheckoutDateTime,,,,,,,',
 u'1842225,10035249209,acbk,namys,MYSTERY ELKINS1999,05/23/2005 03:20:00 PM,,,,,,,',
 u'1928264,10037335444,jcbk,ncpic,E TABACK,12/14/2005 05:56:00 PM,,,,,,,',
 u'1982511,10039952527,jcvhs,ncvidnf,VHS J796.2 KNOW_YO 2000,08/11/2005 01:52:00 PM,,,,,,,',
 u'2026467,10040985615,accd,nacd,CD 782.421642 Y71T,10/19/2005 07:47:00 PM,,,,,,,']
```

Comment: How can we understand the error if you don't provide the source code?

Comment: Sorry for that I will upload it.

Comment: Add a bit of the input data too, it looks like it should be a tuple and not a string as you have assumed.

Comment: Now that you have uploaded your sample.. what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Also add any code you are using to read the file into the rdd. For instance, do you call `split()` at any point?

Answer (score 0):

From the error, it looks like the `rdd` is not RDD[String] but RDD[Tuple] and since you are trying to apply `startswith` which is a python string function, it fails.

You can try something like this:

`test = rdd.filter(lambda line: line[0][0].startsWith("I"))`

The above will filter your RDD and return records whose first element of the tuple starts with `I`.

Comment: Thank you for your response first, but what if I want to apply whole rows in rdd ?

Comment: I tried above your code, but it did not work unfortunately with following error : ERROR scheduler.LiveListenerBus: Listener EventLoggingListener threw an exception
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Comment: That code snippet was shared with the assumption that the first element in the `Tuple` is a string. If it is not a string element, it will fail again. You have to use it with the element that is string. BTW, sharing a sample of your input would help.

Comment: Ok,, I will upload the sample, thanks you can see my writings.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have already created the rdd with multiple attributes, and you want to select only which starts with I, you have to apply the rdd on the particular attribute only.

I believe the below code should do for you,

```
test=rdd.filter(lambda line:line[0].startsWith("I"))
test.take(2)
```

Here the assumption is the line[0], index is the column where you have the column on which you are filtering.
If you only have one attribute in the rdd, then also it should work